# A variable name member of two namespaces

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Let we've written a program which defined variable name as a member of two namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
    extern int a;
}

namespace B
{
    extern int A::a;
}
```

Is `A::a` a member of two `A` and `B` simultaneously? I need in proof as reference to a clause of standard.

Comment: That doesn´t even compile for me...

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is illegal and will fail to compile. A similar question would be this modified example:

```
namespace A {
   namespace B {
      extern int x; // 1
   }
   extern int B::x; // 2
}
extern int A::B::x; // 3
```

All three declarations refer to exactly the same variable, in all cases the variable being declared is `::A::B::x` of type `int`.

As of the quote from the standard, it is not trivial to find something direct and clear, but 8.3/1 contains a *proof* (rather than definition):

> [...] When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers [...]

The above clearly states that both [2] and [3], due to the qualification in the name must refer to a previously declared element of the namespace `B`, in this case the one declared in [1].